# Why this order of events in a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

This is the code that I'm running:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task HelloTest()
    {
        List<int> hello = new List<int>();
       //await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(async x => await Say(hello)));
        await Say(hello);
        await Say(hello);
    }

    private static async Task Say(List<int> hello)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        var rep = new Random().Next();
        hello.Add(rep);
    }
```

Why is it that running this code, as it is, works as intended and results in two random numbers, but that using the commented code instead always results in two of the exact same number?

Comment: what does `GotANumber` do? I do not see that much of a semantical difference here

Comment: @olydis Just returns an int

Comment: since you are talking about "the same" and "correct" values I guess it is more than that?

Comment: Say gets called twice, the numbers returned are unique

Comment: Why not just show us the GotANumber implementation?

Comment: @MattSmith The logic isn't important to the question, just trying to keep the question short. GotANumber is just a placeholder for some logic that returns unique numbers. Sorry if the question was unclear

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the usage of `async` here is just confusing things.  The method `Say` is completely synchronous, and so when it is awaited, it will always return a completed `Task`, and so the calling awaiter will continue synchronously itself.  So, if that's correct, then you should be able to rewrite the problem without `async`/`await` and have the same issue.

Comment: Keeping the question short is only valuable if it is also complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have several issues here.

First, why are you seeing the same value twice.  That's the easy one.  When you create a `Random` instance it is seeded with the current time, but the precision of the current time it uses is rather low.  If you get two new `Random` instances within say 16 milliseconds or so (which is a *really* long time for a computer) you'll see the same values out of them.  That's what's happening for you.

Normally the fix for that is just to share a single `Random` instance, but the problem there is that your random instances aren't being accessed from the same thread (potentially, assuming you don't have a `SynchronizationContext` specified), and `Random` isn't thread safe.  You can use something like this to get your random numbers instead:

```
public static class MyRandom
{
    private static object key = new object();
    private static Random random = new Random();
    public static int Next()
    {
        lock (key)
        {
            return random.Next();
        }
    }

    //TODO add other methods for other `Random` methods as needed
}
```

Use that and it will resolve the immediate issue.

The other problem that you have, although it doesn't seem to be biting you currently, is that you're modifying your `List` from two different tasks, possibly being executed in different threads.  You shouldn't do that.  It's bad enough practice to have methods like this in a single threaded environment (as you're relying on side effects to do your work) but in a multitheraded environment this is *very* problematic, for more than just conceptual reasons.  Instead you should have each thread return a value, and then pull all of those values into a collection on the caller's side, like so:

```
public async Task HelloTest()
{
    var data = await Task.WhenAll(Say(), Say());
}

private static async Task<int> Say()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    return MyRandom.Next();
}
```

As to why the two `Say` calls are run in parallel, rather than sequentially, that has to do with the fact that in your second code snippet you aren't actually waiting for one task to complete before starting the next.

The method that you pass to `Select` is the method to spin up the task, and it won't block until that task is done before starting the next.  The code that you have here:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(async x => await Say(hello)));
```

Is no different than simply having:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(x => Say(hello)));
```

Having an `async` method that does nothing but await one method call is really no different than just having that one method call.  What's happening here is that `Select` is calling `Say`, staring the task, continuing on, which stats the next task, and then `WhenAll` is waiting (asynchronously) for both tasks to finish before continuing on.

Comment: that was really interesting about Random (seeding with time and not being thread safe).  That was news to me.

Comment: @MattSmith Questions are posted as a result of that first issue most days on SO.  It's rarer for them to be tied into multithreaded applications, but still not unheard of.  I'm actually astounded that you've never come across it before given the number of questions you've come across.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is an answer to the *original* question (the question has since been changed).

They operate identically.  I ran the below Console application and got the results 0 1 for both versions:

```
class Program
{
    static int m_nextNumber = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = Version1();

        m_nextNumber = 0;
        var t2 = Version2();

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task Version1()
    {
        List<int> hello = new List<int>();
        await Say(hello);
        await Say(hello);
        PrintHello(hello);
    }

    static async Task Version2()
    {
        List<int> hello = new List<int>();
        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Select(async x => await Say(hello)));
        PrintHello(hello);
    }

    static void PrintHello(List<int> hello)
    {
        foreach (var i in hello)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    static int GotANumber()
    {
        return m_nextNumber++;
    }

    static async Task Say(List<int> hello)
    {
        var rep = GotANumber();
        hello.Add(rep);
    }
}
```